# Given list of subset in thousands, find best match set between pre-processed set and some random super set

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

Given finder : List of map, key : String, Val : String.

On receiving super map : a map which is super set of one or more map in a finder, find map from finder list which has contains maximum elements from super map.

For instance

```
Map { Name = Adam, Qualification = Engg, Job = Manager , Country =  US, City = Seattle}
```

list of sub maps :

```
   List [ submap1 {Name = Adam, Job = Manager }, 
  submap2 {Name = Adam, Country = Us, city - Seattle}
  submap3 {Name = Adam, Country = Us, city - Seattle, Job = 
    manager, Nickname = bobby}]
```

Result should be submap2. Is there a way I could utilise tries to preprocess list of sublist for faster look ups. Given that I have list of submaps at compile time and on receiving super map I need to find the best sub map.

Looking for some pointers on algo and datastructure i could use to preprocess sub lists and to match any  super-set faster. Some sort of trie based structure ?

Comment: Hi sidss - can you show us the code that you have written so far? Also, in what language are you working? E.g. Java, C#, etc.

Comment: Havn't written any code yet. Plean to write in Java. Looking for some pointer on algo and data structure that i can use to preprocess sub sets to match faster. Some sort of Trie based structure.

Comment: Your best bet is to write some code - even if it's not working - and then to ask you question. StackOverflow (SO) works best when people can help you figure out what's wrong with your code rather than writing the code for you. Good luck with your homework assignment!

Comment: Vince, I am not looking for code. Some pointer on how if i could use tries based matcher.